# Append os.listdir neatly

Tags: operating-system, wxpython

With this code in a TextCtrl I get:

```
os.listdir(self.dirname)
self.bottomview.AppendText(str(os.listdir(self.dirname)))
>>>[u'a.txt', u'b.txt', u'c.txt']
```

How would you append os.listdir so that it lists like:

```
a.txt
b.txt
c.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried it in normal python and the below command works -

```
print "\n".join(os.listdir(self.dirname))
```

See if this works well in `wxpython` also.

Comment: Thats it.  I would have never guess to add newline before join.